# On a conjecture of Pierce concerning direct decomposition of Abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory

It has been shown that for any positive integer $r$ there exists a countable torsion-free abelian group $G$ such that the direct sum of $m$ copies of $G$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of $n$ copies of $G$ if and only if $m \equiv n (\mod r)$.

My question is that is the torsion-free abelian group $G$ in the above statement of finite rank?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If $G$ has rank $k<\infty$ then $G^{r+1}$ has rank $k(r+1)$, so $G\not\cong G^{r+1}$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thank you for your help.